# $p,q,r \in \mathbb{R}$ and $pqr≠0$, if $f(x)=x^3-px^2+qx-r=(x-p)(x-q)(x-r)$, then find the value of $f(3)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$p,q,r\in \mathbb{R}$ and $pqr\not=0$, if $f(x)=x^3-px^2+qx-r=(x-p)(x-q)(x-r)$, then find the value of $f(3)$?
the options are:

- 24
- 26
- 28
- 30
- 32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand $(x-p)(x-q)(x-r)=x^3-(p+q+r)x^2+(pq+pr+qr)x-pqr$ and compare coefficients of like powers of $x$ with $x^3-p x^2+q x-r$, yielding:
\begin{align}
-(p+q+r)&=-p &\text{(1)}\\
pq+pr+qr&=q &\text{(2)}\\
-pqr &= -r&\text{(3)}
\end{align}
Now (1) implies $r=-q$, and substituting this in (2) yields $-q^2=q$, so $q=-1$ and $r=1$. Then (3) implies $p = -1$.  Finally, $f(3)=(3+1)(3+1)(3-1)=32$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $p$,$q$,$r$ are the roots of $f(x)$,

\begin{eqnarray}
f(p) &=& pq - r = 0 \newline
f(q) &=& q^{3} - (p-1)q^{2} - r = 0 \newline
f(r) &=& r(r^{2} - rp + q -1) = 0
\end{eqnarray}

Solving these equations, we get -

\begin{eqnarray}
&& p = -1 , q=-1 , r=1 \newline
&& f(3) = (3+1)(3+1)(3-1) = 32
\end{eqnarray}